# Vertical scrolling so that the text cursor is always centered in ScrolledText widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a `tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText` widget for reading a large book (about one megabyte). I constantly change the position of the text cursor. How can I make automatic vertical scrolling so that the text cursor is always centered on the `ScrolledText` widget?

```py
...
from tkinter import scrolledtext
...
self.annotation_text_area = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.frame_right_annotation, wrap=tk.WORD, font=("Arial", self.options["fontsize"]), bg=self.options["bg"], fg=self.options["fg"])
self.annotation_text_area.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.RIGHT,expand=True, pady=5)
self.annotation_text_area.insert(tk.END, self.book)
self.annotation_text_area.bind('<Button-1>', self.annotation_click)
...
def annotation_click(self, event):
    pass
    # ???
```

I change position text cursor:

```py
...
self.annotation_text_area.mark_set("insert", f"{count_lines}.{count_chars}")
self.annotation_text_area.see("insert")
...
```

but there is no scrolling to center...

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to take advantage of the fact that the `yview` method of the internal widget is called whenever the view in the window changes. We can create a proxy so that we notice when that command is called, and when it is called we can call a function to adjust the selection.

Here's a simple example that illustrates the point. It uses the selection tag (`"sel"`), but you could use any tag you want, of course. It's probably not an optimal solution, but it shows the general concept.

It's a little bit jerky, because the scroll doesn't always scroll in whole line increments, so the middle line might move up and down just a bit.

```
import tkinter as tk

class CustomText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # create a proxy for the underlying widget so that
        # we can catch calls to the `yview` command.
        self._orig = self._w + "_orig"
        self.tk.call("rename", self._w, self._orig)
        self.tk.createcommand(self._w, self._proxy)

        # also, reset the highlighted line whenever the widget
        # changes size.
        self.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: self.highlight_center_line())

    def _proxy(self, command, *args):
        cmd = (self._orig, command) + args
        try:
            result = self.tk.call(cmd)
        except:
            result = ""

        if command == "yview":
            self.after_idle(self.highlight_center_line)

        return result

    def highlight_center_line(self):
        y = self.winfo_height() //2
        self.tk.call((self._orig, "tag", "remove", "sel", "1.0", "end"))
        self.tk.call((self._orig, "tag", "add", "sel", f"@0,{y}", f"@0,{y} lineend +1c"))

root = tk.Tk()
text = CustomText(root, wrap="word")
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=text.yview)
text.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

for i in range(500):
    text.insert("end", f"Line {i+1}\n")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, this is probably close to what I need. like a string ```self.tk.call((self._orig, "tag", "add", "sel", f"@0,{y}", f"@0,{y} lineend +1c"))``` to indicate that it is necessary not to select the center but to do scrolling?

Comment: line code ```y = self.winfo_height() // 2``` i change with ```y = math.trunc(self.winfo_height() / 2.0)``` so it's probably better

Comment: @xayam: why do you think that's better? It seems to return the exact same result.